# Only enter a trade once per bar when calc_on_order_fills=true, Pine Script, Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, trading

I want to add one of the following conditions to avoid my strategy entering a trade on a bar where already a trade was entered.
Eg: Last trade was entered at 12 o´clock on an 1 hour chart and was closed by the trailing stop function into this same bar. Now the next entry for a trade should be earliest in the beginning of the next bar  (`calc_on_order_fills` is set to `true`)

```
strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades) != bar_index

strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades) != time
```

But it doesn´t work.
Can anyone please help to solve this issue? And explain to me why it doesn´t work?

EDIT:

```
//Submit entry orders
if (LongCondition and time>timestamp(2022, 07, 01, 06, 00) and strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1) < bar_index)
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long, alert_message = "Place Long Order", comment = "Long Entry")


if (ShortCondition and time>timestamp(2022, 07, 01, 06, 00) and strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1) < bar_index)
    strategy.entry(id = "Short", direction = strategy.short, alert_message = "Place Short Order", comment = "Short Entry")
```

Without this: `and strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1) < bar_index` it works, but with several entrys in one bar. And that´s what I try to avoid.

Comment: In general - `strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index()` function receives `trade_num` which is 0 based, while `strategy.closedtrades` is a variable of the number of trades, and the first trade number is 1. That means that you need to write `strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1)` to get the `bar_index` of the last closed trade and accordingly `strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades - 1)` to get `entry_time` of the last closed trade

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! 
But if I use it, it looks like before. Alle the trades disappear from the chart. I edited the strategy.entry script above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I added this condition:

```
and (strategy.closedtrades == 0 or strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades-1) < bar_index)
```

the key part is

```
strategy.closedtrades == 0
```

otherwise, you never get into a trade